# Calculate average for nested List

Tags: java, list, average

Please tell me an effective way to calculate the average for this structure.

Example:

```
List<Double> one = Arrays.asList(-17.3, -1.3, 22.3);
List<Double> two = Arrays.asList(-2.3, 12.2, -75.3);
List<Double> three = Arrays.asList(-0.3, 72.0, -22.1);

List<List<Double>> montSensorMetrics = new ArrayList<>();
montSensorMetrics.add(one);
montSensorMetrics.add(two);
montSensorMetrics.add(three);
```

Expecting :

```
R = ((-17.3) + (-2.3) + (-0.3)) / 3

List<Double> result = new ArrayList<>();
result.add(R)
```

Now, I have created a method for calculating the average:

```
public List<Double> calculateAverageForMetric(List<List<Double>> montSensorMetrics) {
    List<Double> sumAccumulator = new ArrayList<> ();

    for (int j = 0; j < montSensorMetrics.size(); j++) {
        //add first set as is
        if (j == 0) {
            sumAccumulator.addAll(montSensorMetrics.get(j));
            j++;
        }

        var metricData = montSensorMetrics.get(j);

        for (int i = 0; i < metricData.size(); i++) {
            double elementValueInAccumulator = sumAccumulator.get(i);
            double currentValueInMetric = metricData.get(i);
            double sum = elementValueInAccumulator + currentValueInMetric;
            sumAccumulator.set(i, sum);
        }
    }

    return sumAccumulator.stream().map(v - > v / montSensorMetrics.size()).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Can you please tell me, is this the right decision?

Comment: Q: You don't think [List.add()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) adds the elements of list together arithmetically, do you?  You know ".add()" just appends one list to another, right? Q: So what exactly is your question?

Comment: Java code is provided for illustrative purposes. And to the core of the issue does not directly affect. I wanted to show what the structure looks like over which it is necessary to take actions to calculate the arithmetic mean.

How exactly I showed a little lower. I need to take turns adding the values of the nested List and putting the result in another sheet.

Comment: You can use streams(Java 8)

Answer (score 1):

I have used Java 8 stream to get the average of each list.

```
List<Double> one = Arrays.asList(-17.3, -1.3, 22.3);
List<Double> two = Arrays.asList(-2.3, 12.2, -75.3);
List<Double> three = Arrays.asList(-0.3, 72.0, -22.1);

List<List<Double>> montSensorMetrics = new ArrayList<>();
montSensorMetrics.add(one);
montSensorMetrics.add(two);
montSensorMetrics.add(three);

List<Double> averageValues = IntStream.range(0,montSensorMetrics.size()).mapToDouble(pos -> montSensorMetrics.stream().mapToDouble(outer -> outer.get(pos)).sum()).map(a -> a/montSensorMetrics.size()).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(averageValues);
```

Comment: For each? Look carefully at the example in the post, the average for the column is considered there.